# Notify the client computers using pop-up balloons

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, notifications, popup

How can I notify the client computers using the pop-up balloons?? I really don't know how to do it.

E.G. I will assigned a new task for the employees, when I click a button, the task will be saved to the DB. And a balloon with a title and the name of employee will pop-up in the clients computers.

Saving the task in DB is done. but the pop-up balloons?? How?? I searched it over the net but it seems I can find exact answer.

I already did an email notifications but I think email notification will not help me to speed up the notifications for the employees.

Thank you everyone who will helped me. This will finished my proposed system.

Comment: Winform or Web? if winform simply put a timer control on the main form, and each minute or so ping the dB to see if there is any updates. This is the popup notification control I used and it worked really well: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3285/TaskbarNotifier-a-skinnable-MSN-Messenger-like-pop

Comment: @JeremyThompson, Hi, I'm sorry it is WinForm.. please help me. Thanks..

Comment: @JeremyThompson, how can I put a timer control on my main form?? can you give me structure how to do it??? thanks..

Comment: View the Winform in Design Time, drag and drop a Timer control onto the form. Then F4 to see the Timer's properties > set the Enabled property to True and the Interval property to 6000 millisec's (1 minute). Then in the Properties window see the Lighting Bolt icon > click that and you will see the Timer Controls' events > double click the Tick event.. and that event will fire every minute when your application is in run-mode.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, Thanks for giving me the idea, im working on it. and hope for success. I will be back later.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy Thompson. My is now solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you save the data to the DB, you also need to broadcast the new assignment to all clients. You can achieve this by implementing a client/server architecture where upon program startup, all clients connect to a central server (it could be the DB Server itself, if you are allowed to do this) that broadcasts these messages. Once a client receives a message, you can use the NotifyIcon control in .NET. A [full working example on how to use NotifyIcon can be read here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx)

You may think about redundancy as far as not having only one central server but rather implementing a ring topology in which messages are passed along the ring, for example.

You could also implement this using a [Message Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx).

The balloon notification is the easiest part; it's literally 3 or 4 lines of code. Broadcasting the messages (or polling for them) is more involved.

**EDIT**

Piggybacking a bit on Jeremy's comment, you could also poll the DB itself for new messages. In your program you'd have to keep track of which messages (records) have been retrieved as to not to display repeated notifications. You could easily do this by keeping track of the last record id the program has retrieved. On program start up, you'll need to get the current latest so that going forward you start showing notifications.

Comment: hi, yes all my clients are connected to the DB in my Server. Can you tell me how to broadcast a messages using DB Server?? thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sir, I know how to use NotifyIcon, but the thing is I dont know to broadcast a message to my clients... sorry

Comment: You need to write the code that broadcasts the messages yourself. *It's very unlikely* your DB offers this functionality out of the box. The easiest thing to do is to poll the DB for new records at certain time intervals but this could be inefficient.

Comment: I've done this before, the clients queried every minute.  I used it to kick everyone out of the app before I would start an update.

Comment: @Kevzz - Is your question regarding which technology to use for broadcasting the notifications or do you have a specific technology in mind for achieving this?

Comment: @M.Babcock, I dont have any specific technology in mind. I just want to know how to broadcast a message to my clients using C# application and SQL Server. Icarus and Jeremy Thompson, gave the idea on how to do it. So I just started to create the code from their idea.

Comment: Exactly how everyone its telling you, with a timer and notify icon on your main form.  The timers callback queued the database and displays the icon as appropriate.

Comment: Indeed Andy, Im on it.. Thanks.